# How to perform join query in Firebase?

Tags: android, join, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After retrieving group key in HashMap how to perform join query which shows only those `grp` details which have member as that particular user. And if this structure is wrong please help me with this.

Structure:

[image: screenShot]

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/join|sort:date/firebase-talk/DKnBnI0bqoI/YMrp-L1hBgAJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `DatabaseReference` inside another `DatabaseReference`:

```
 // any way you managed to go the node that has the 'grp_key'
    DatabaseReference MembersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Members")
            .child("1CkPG20Tt2dzrVkYkdfCLo")
            .orderByKey().equalTo("-KYnhiAucnasdkadNC")
            .addValueEventListener(
                    new ValueEventListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                        {
                            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            {

                                Map<String, Object> valuesMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                                // Get push id value.
                                String key = valuesMap.get("grp_key");


                                // HERE WHAT CORRESPONDS TO JOIN
                                DatabaseReference chatGroupRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                        .child("Chat_groups")
                                        .orderByKey().equalTo(key)
                                        .addValueEventListener(
                                                new ValueEventListener()
                                                {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                                    {
                                                        // repeat!!
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                                                    {

                                                    }
                                                }
                                        )
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                        {

                        }
                    }
            );
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to combine this data with firebase recycler adapter and thanks alot  #amrelghobary sir

Comment: @ArjunThakkar 
you can join it using [`FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data)

Comment: @ amrelghobary thank you sir. 1 last question if i have one group than all of this working fine, but what if i have multiple groups.That first MembersRef you have mentioned "orderByKey().equalTo("-KYnhiAucnasdkadNC")"  here insted of "-KYnhiAucnasdkadNC" this single rendom  key i have list of random  keys than what should i do ?

Comment: I haven't understand your question very well, but `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` handles all the keys in the passed location for you.

Remember to mark my response as answer, if it helped you!

Comment: @ amrelghobary sir can u explain how to take keyref and database reg in FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter , I have searched alot but i couldnt find a single tutorial on FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter.