# Is there a way to retrieve data in android from Firebase database using "join" query?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I've tried to perform a join query in Firebase, but the code does not return anything. The scenario is that I need to find the user phoneNumber searching after the licence plate. I tried the following way but no success.
I attach the code and the json file from the database.
Thanks

I was trying this solution but it did not worked [How to perform join query in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135658/how-to-perform-join-query-in-firebase)

```
databaseReference.child("cars").child("User"+text.toUpperCase()).orderByChild("licenceNumber").equalTo(text.toUpperCase()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    final Car carNumber = postSnapshot.getValue(Car.class);
                    String UID = carNumber.getId();

                    databaseReference.child("Users").child(UID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                final User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                String phone = user.getPhoneNumber();
                                textView2.setText(phone);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "1HvAKvh9AETSFYMTqbOIq6AlKap2" : {
      "email" : "bb@ll.com",
      "name" : "John",
      "phoneNumber" : "1111"
    },
    "8RxAsvjDMhTugZtbm8etoxcJ6Ts1" : {
      "email" : "nnn@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Jane  Doe",
      "phoneNumber" : "123456789"
    },
    "MuM99wZYuhbpbXxcv3wXxy9IGqh2" : {
      "email" : "Fff@mail.com",
      "id" : "MuM99wZYuhbpbXxcv3wXxy9IGqh2",
      "name" : "Violeta",
      "phoneNumber" : "1234"
    },
    "Np1jymmdVpMi3hqKDrTPdYuSR9g2" : {
      "email" : "ddd@fff.com",
      "id" : "Np1jymmdVpMi3hqKDrTPdYuSR9g2",
      "name" : "Henry",
      "phoneNumber" : "12345"
    },
    "PFalUadu8xf46siLWikQLLeK7L92" : {
      "email" : "Hjjj@hhhh.com",
      "id" : "PFalUadu8xf46siLWikQLLeK7L92",
      "name" : "George",
      "phoneNumber" : "077292"
    }
  },
  "cars" : {
    "1HvAKvh9AETSFYMTqbOIq6AlKap2" : {
      "UserAR99KTA" : {
        "id" : "1HvAKvh9AETSFYMTqbOIq6AlKap2",
        "licenceNumber" : "AR99KTA"
      }
    },
    "8RxAsvjDMhTugZtbm8etoxcJ6Ts1" : {
      "UserGG77HHH" : {
        "id" : "8RxAsvjDMhTugZtbm8etoxcJ6Ts1",
        "licenceNumber" : "GG77HHH"
      },
      "UserHHHVVFF" : {
        "id" : "8RxAsvjDMhTugZtbm8etoxcJ6Ts1",
        "licenceNumber" : "HHHVVFF"
      },
      "UserSV07WNE" : {
        "id" : "8RxAsvjDMhTugZtbm8etoxcJ6Ts1",
        "licenceNumber" : "UU07WUE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual "join" query that you want to perform?

Comment: The scenario is that I need to find the user phoneNumber searching after the licence plate